# migrated a windowsforms project from visual studio to monodevelop on linux, no errors. Why application is running very slow?

Tags: linux, winforms, mono, monodevelop, winforms-interop

I migrated a windowsforms project from visual studio to monodevelop on linux.I built in monodevelop, i am getting no errors but my application is running very slow.
Please anyone help me do i need to do any code changes for my windowsforms.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to profile your application on Mono, http://mono-project.com/Profiler, as it should be application specific. The profiling result should help you better understand what is the cause.

Mono has its differences from .NET, so in some edge cases your application might crash or be slow. You will have to dive deeper so as to locate the culprit.